# Eevee bad quality shadows near another face

Tags: eevee-render-engine, lighting, shadows

[image: Low quality shadows that should not be cast]

So I am doing an architecture design for my art class and I decided to use Eevee to speed up the render time for the animation I was planning. However, I have some issues with the lighting here because there are shadows cast at different spots where they should not and on top of that they are in a pretty low quality.
I am using IrradianceVolume to make the interior lighting more realistic, if that is important. I also take use of contact shadows but as far as I know they are not the problem here.

[image: Settings: Maxed Cube and Cascade Size]
[image: Light that is responsible for all of the lighting of the scene right now]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Alright for anyone having same issues:
It was because of the **IrradianceVolume Settings**.

The Probes were to close to the walls and the Falloff was too high. That caused the weird shadows aka. the points were the light wasn't calculated anymore because of the high falloff.